# TieredMenu and calendar date selection in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, menu, calendar

I have a tiered menu with a calendar date selector in it. I want calendar popup to be closed after selection but not tiered menu. But when I select a date from calendar popup, tiered menu closes instead of calendar popup.Is there a way to get desired behaviour?

[image: tiered menu with calendar popup]

```
<p:commandButton id="advancedSearchBtn" icon="fa fa-caret-down" value="" type="button" />
<p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="advancedSearchBtn" my="left top" at="left bottom" >

<p:menuitem>

    <p:panel >
        <h:outputText style="color:black" value="Content" />
        <p:inputText value="#{searchBean.searchContent}" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText  value="Author" />
        <p:inputText value="#{searchBean.searchAuthor}" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="Başlangıç Tarihi" />
        <p:calendar value="#{searchBean.startDate}"
                    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" 
                    style="width:20px;"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>           
        <h:outputText value="Bitiş Tarihi" />
        <p:calendar value="#{searchBean.finishDate}"
                    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" 
                    style="width:20px;"/>
    </p:panel>
</p:menuitem>
```

Comment: I have done some experiments. Changing  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" from  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" made calendar able to close automatically on date selection. It was not closing at previous version coz waiting for time selection.

Comment: Another finding: Tiered menu closes when click on calendar popup is beyond tiered menu border. If parts of popup inside(coinciding) tiered menu is clicked, menu does not close